# change Class property properties (verbose_name exmpl.) from base Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an abstract class with **name** and **slug** field.when i inherit from another class i want to change verbose_name parameter according to that class. How can I set this properties? I want to set the verbose_name parameter of the name field to "foo". but I want to use different parameter data for two different classes.

An example:

For ProductModel name field **verbose_name**="Foo"

For CategoryModel name field **verbose_name**="Poo"

```
class BaseProductModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="name",unique=True,verbose_name="Slug")

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class ProductModel(BaseProductModel):
    # I want to set the verbose_Name parameter of the name field to "foo".
    #The two fields (name and slug) come from the inherited (BaseProductModel) class.
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Detay")

class CategoryModel(BaseProductModel):
    # The two fields (name and slug) come from the inherited (BaseProductModel) class.
    # I want to set the verbose_Name parameter of the name field to "Poo".
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

First, works only for abstract classes, otherwise it will change verbose_name of parent class too:

```
class ProductModel(BaseProductModel):
    # I want to set the verbose_Name parameter of the name field to "foo".
    #The two fields (name and slug) come from the inherited (BaseProductModel) class.
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Detay")

ProductModel.get_field('name').verbose_name = 'Foo'
```

And second, do that in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    field = self._meta.get_field('name')
    field.verbose_name = 'Foo'
```